# Easiest way to create an area raster

Tags: qgis, arcmap, gdal, matlab

The objective is to create a global geotiff raster at 30s resolution (appr 1km) with the pixel value the area of that pixel. I have multiple tools but struggle to find the easiest way. I am aware of this [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/127165/more-accurate-way-to-calculate-area-of-rasters)  and probably prefer an answer using GDAL.

QGIS:

1. create grid,
2. use raster calculator to obtain area per polygon
3. rasterize featurr\es

Matlab:

1. Areamat function

Earth Engine:

1. ee.Image.pixelArea()

ArcMap: 
?

GDAL/ Python
?

Other
?

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if this is the easier, but using Python (Numpy) and GDAL, I think the following code works. I have calculated the grid cell size from the usual formula, and you need to provide the grid resolution in decimal degrees.

```py
import numpy as np
import gdal
"""
Creates a global grid of a particular resolution, where the value of
each grid cell is the area of that grid cell in sqm.
"""

def do_grid (resolution=0.5):
    """Calculate the area of each grid cell for a user-provided
    grid cell resolution. Area is in square meters, but resolution
    is given in decimal degrees."""
    # Calculations needs to be in radians
    lats = np.deg2rad(np.arange(-90,90, resolution))
    r_sq = 6371000**2
    n_lats = int(360./resolution) 
    area = r_sq*np.ones(n_lats)[:, None]*np.deg2rad(resolution)*(
                np.sin(lats[1:]) - np.sin(lats[:-1]))
    return area.T

if __name__ == "__main__":
    resolution=0.5
    # Get the GeoTIFF driver
    drv = gdal.GetDriverByName("GTiff")
    # Compressed GeoTIFF file
    dst_ds = drv.Create("grid.tif", int(360./resolution),
                int(180./resolution), 
                1, gdal.GDT_Float32,
                options = [ 'COMPRESS=DEFLATE'] )
    # Projection using EPSG:4326
    wgs84='GEOGCS["WGS 84",DATUM["WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],UNIT["degree",0.01745329251994328,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]'
    dst_ds.SetProjection(wgs84)
    geotransform = (-180.,resolution,0,90.,0,-resolution)
    dst_ds.SetGeoTransform(geotransform)
    dst_ds.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray(do_grid(resolution=resolution))
    dst_ds = None
```

Comment: thank you for this answer. If I am not mistaken, this will only work with rasters smaller than your memory.

Comment: Well, you can just create chunks of the raster and write them out. Or you could create a coarser resolution raster and then use gdalwarp it to the desired resolution. This second option is easier I think.